# window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn doesn't send callback in Safari

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-javascript-client

We embedded Google OAuth button inside iframe. When user loads a page with this iframe, clicks Google button from that iframe, window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn fires and new window appears. User enters email, password and submits form. Window closes but there is no callback to this function.

It only reproduces when main window domain is different to iframe domain!

You can try here - https://sparklejobs.com/localhost-universal/

Main window domain - sparklejobs.com
Iframe window with Google button - staging-web.good.co

Comment: My exact issue. I'm still trying to implements a workaround so I can't "Answer" this question, but I can give you some hints after reading lots of stuff about this issue. First of all Disabling (oddly enough) `Allow Cross-site tracking` Seems to be an option. Also take a look at these: https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/503#issuecomment-687741866 and https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/260#issuecomment-675055603